KEDA ScaledObject fails with error no account given despite providing accountId and queryKey directly in ScaledObject
I'm trying to set up autoscaling for my Kubernetes deployment using KEDA with New Relic as a trigger. However, I'm encountering an error despite providing the necessary accountId and queryKey directly in the ScaledObject. Here are the error logs from the KEDA operator:
error parsing new-relic metadata: missing required field in scaler config: no account given

trigger-secret.yaml
apiVersion: v1
data:
  accountId: <ACCOUNT ID>
  queryKey: <Query Key>
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: newrelic-secret
  namespace: default

trigger-auth.yaml
apiVersion: keda.sh/v1alpha1
kind: TriggerAuthentication
metadata:
  name: newrelic-auth
  namespace: default
spec:
  secretTargetRef:
    - parameter: accountId
      name: newrelic-secret
      key: accountId
    - parameter: queryKey
      name: newrelic-secret
      key: queryKey


scaled-object.yaml
apiVersion: keda.sh/v1alpha1
kind: ScaledObject
metadata:
  name: devfest-app-scaledobject
  namespace: default
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: devfest-app-2024 # Your application deployment name
  minReplicaCount: 1 # Minimum number of replicas
  maxReplicaCount: 10 # Maximum number of replicas
  pollingInterval: 30  # Interval to check metrics (in seconds)
  cooldownPeriod: 300  # Scale down after 5 minutes of inactivity
  triggers:
    - type: new-relic
      metadata:
        accountId: <ACCOUNT ID>
        queryKey: <Query Key>
        region: "US" # Set your New Relic region (US/EU)
        query: |
          SELECT rate(count(*), 1 minute) 
          FROM Transaction 
          WHERE appName = 'devfest-app-2024' 
          SINCE 5 minute ago
        threshold: "5" # Set the threshold (e.g., 5 requests/min)
      authenticationRef:
        name: newrelic-auth

Error Log from KEDA Operator:
2024-12-04T15:27:57Z    ERROR   failed to ensure HPA is correctly created for ScaledObject  {"controller": "scaledobject", "controllerGroup": "keda.sh", "controllerKind": "ScaledObject", "ScaledObject": {"name":"devfest-app-scaledobject","namespace":"default"}, "namespace": "default", "name": "devfest-app-scaledobject", "reconcileID": "4bb7ff07-dd52-48fb-bcc2-b6d2c01b1a23", "error": "error parsing new-relic metadata: missing required field in scaler config: no account given"}
github.com/kedacore/keda/v2/controllers/keda.(*ScaledObjectReconciler).Reconcile
    /workspace/controllers/keda/scaledobject_controller.go:195
sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/internal/controller.(*Controller[...]).Reconcile

I've tried embedding the accountId and queryKey directly in the ScaledObject YAML as shown above, but the error persists.
What am I missing here?
Is there a specific way KEDA expects the accountId and queryKey to be provided for the New Relic trigger?
Should I reference the TriggerAuthentication even if I provide the credentials directly in the ScaledObject?
Any help or insights on why this error occurs would be greatly appreciated!

As per keda New Relic documentation, I changed accountId to account and it worked.
